# Explanation of inequality $|x+y|^p \leq 2^p(x^p + y^p)$, where $p>0$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Is there an obvious reason why this inequality is true for all $p > 0$? 
$$|x+y|^p \leq 2^p(|x|^p + |y|^p)$$
I found it in Royden's book, where the authors claims it is obvious.

Comment: $|x+y|\leq 2\max\{|x|,|y|\}$, now raise both sides to the $p$-th power.

Comment: Sorry I just figured it out.  My bad

Comment: Just use information about mediums, and note that $|x+y|^p \leq 2^p(|x|^p + |y|^p) \Longleftrightarrow |\frac{x+y}{2}|^p \leq |x|^p +|y|^p$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$|x+y|^p \leq |2\max\{|x|,|y|\}|^p = 2^p |\max\{|x|,|y|\}|^p \leq 2^p(|x|^p + |y|^p).$$