# What is the generalization of the inequality $\vert x+y\vert^p\leq 2^p(\vert x\vert^p +\vert y\vert^p)?$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

What is the generalization to $m$- elements ($m\geq 2$) of the well known inequality
$$\vert x+y\vert^p\leq 2^p(\vert x\vert^p +\vert y\vert^p)?$$

Could anyone help me or give some references? A proof will be well accepted too. Thank you in advance!

Comment: It should be straightforward to generalize this proof https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1023440/42969 to more than two numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For  $x_1,\ldots,x_n$,

$$|x_1+\ldots +x_n|\leq |x_1|+\ldots +|x_n|\leq n\max\{|x_k|:1\leq k\leq n\}$$

From this, it follows that

$$\begin{align}
|x_1+\ldots +x_n|^p&\leq (|x_1|+\ldots +|x_n|)^p\\
&\leq n^p\max\{|x_k|^p:1\leq k\leq n\}\leq n^p(|x_1|^p+\ldots |x_n|^p)
\end{align}$$

Here we are using the monotonicity of $x\mapsto x^p$ (assuming $p>0$).

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality we can consider both $x, y$ positive as the right hand side does not change for positive or negative values of $x, y$ , but the left hand side reduces if the signs are opposite. Divide  both sides by $2^p$ . Then it is simple $RMS-AM$ inequality. Generalization is also $ RMS-AM$ inequality.